# Postgres convert integer into text

Tags: postgresql

I have a question. I'm using a Postgrs database, and my problem is that I need to use the ints as text. I have the following solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(integer) RETURNS text STRICT IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS 'SELECT textin(int4out($1));';

CREATE CAST (integer AS text) WITH FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(integer) AS IMPLICIT;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION pg_catalog.text(integer) IS 'convert integer to text';
```

I had been reading that this solution is not correct, it can cause some problems in the future. So I had been doing a research through the internet and I saw some people only use CAST, but just to convert a specific int, i.e., https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82511/how-to-enable-implicit-casts-in-postgresql-9-2

Comment: Hi, could you clarify your problem a bit? Are you asking what the problems with implicit casts are, or how to solve a particular problem without needing implicit casts? What is the actual problem you're hoping the implicit cast will help you with?

Comment: I use many databases, Oracle, Mysql and sqlserver, and with those, I can use the numbers as text, but with Postgre I can't. So I want to cast those integers into text, and I had the solution posted, but I had been reading that my solution will cause many problems on my application because I'm editing a pg_catalog function, so I ask how can I use the CAST function alone without the function defined. Thanks.

Comment: The function you posted is the way to make Postgres "implicitly cast" integers to text, i.e. without changing your queries. `CAST` is the keyword for "explicit casts", i.e. changing your SQL to read `SELECT CAST(some_int as VarChar)` rather than `SELECT some_int`.

Comment: You should stop treating numbers as text - not only because Postgres is stricter (which is better in my opinion) but because it's bad coding style. Oracle and MySQL might let you get away with being sloppy but that's not an excuse for treating numbers and strings the same way. If you try to do something like that in a strongly type programming language like Java your program wouldn't even compile

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The danger with creating an implicit cast like that is that it destabilizes the carefully balanced type system in PostgreSQL; after that, some innocent invocations of overloaded functions will stop working because due to the cast, there are suddenly too many candidate functions to make a unique choice.

It is much better to use an explicit cast:

```
CAST (intcol AS text)
```

That is standard SQL and should work everywhere.

Comment: The OP's example is the other way around (`CAST(int_col as VarChar)`)

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL have shorthand for casting with `::` operator.

Example of usage:

```sql
select 1 as "i am number", 1::text as "i am text";
```

[image: example result]

You can use it on any column by replace `1` in example with column name.

[documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE)